# How to use Google Safe Browsing after applying an API key in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've read through the get-started documentation, but I am still confused on where to actually begin in `ruby` on rails.

This is the given url:

```
https://sb-ssl.google.com/safebrowsing/api/lookup?client=CLIENT&key=APIKEY&appver=APPVER&pver=PVER&url=URL
```

After I fill in these five arguments, how should I use this url to get the HTTP response?

Should I get string or integer : 200, 204, 400 ... etc?